# pygtk menubar with fixed

Tags: gtk, pygtk, fixed, menubar

I'm new to pyGTK, and now I'm trying to create a menubar with a fixed layout, but I only get a background on the items, not on the entire bar. My code:

```
import gtk

class App(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App,self).__init__()
        self.set_size_request(640,480)
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)

        menubar = gtk.MenuBar()

        menu_file= gtk.Menu()
        menuitem_file = gtk.MenuItem("File")
        menuitem_file.set_submenu(menu_file)

        menuitem_exit = gtk.MenuItem("Exit")
        menuitem_exit.connect("activate",gtk.main_quit)
        menu_file.append(menuitem_exit)

        menubar.append(menuitem_file)

        fixed = gtk.Fixed()

        vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 2)
        vbox.pack_start(menubar, False, False, 0)

        fixed.add(vbox)

        self.add(fixed)

        self.connect("destroy",gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

App ()
gtk.main ()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `vbox` request size, e.g. add `vbox.set_size_request (300,50)` and see the difference. It is not correct size, but then I don't know why you use `gtk.Fixed` at all. In 99.95% of case you *don't* need `gtk.Fixed`. And especially if you are new to GTK+ you might think you need it while you actually don't.

Comment: OK, but how do I layout my widgets then?